# How can I organize/sort my shopping cart by item collection.?

Tags: sorting, shopify, cart, liquid

How can I organize/sort my shopping cart by item collection. Cant figure out how to do it in shopify (cart-template.liquid) any tips?

Comment: Hi, please be as descriptive as possible. Possibly include your setup, technology(ies) that are being used, etc. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I got 4,000 products in my shopify page with differente collections/vendors. I want to show the customers in the shopping cart what items have they bought from each vendor or collection. For example if I buy 3 cokes and two boxes from Walmart and 5 bottles of water from Walgreens. In the shopping cart I will like to see this:

Vendor/Collection: Walmart
-Coke
-Boxes

Vendor/Collection: Walgreens
-Water
-etc.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this without a heck of a lot of programming. Shopify fails to provide the collection an item is assigned to when it is added to cart, so without that attribute, it is all up to you to record the collection at the time something is added to cart. With that attribute, obviously you could render the cart and then re-order by collection.

It is actually a very weak aspect of Shopify in terms of marketing and reporting that you never know which collections are responsible for best selling products. You can only guess or as I said, manually make that a think for yourself. Or take apart Google Analytics code where that might be a thing too. In fact, I am betting Shopify probably wipes their hands clean of this due to reliance on Analytics code to be this kind of data source.

Comment: I have searched everywhere and no one can help with this. Can it be done by vendors instead of collections? Thank you!

Comment: I got it to show each item's collection under the Product Title. I guess I'll try to change my sorting by tags or vendors. Lastly ill try to program it.

Comment: Ordering by vendor is simple. Each product has a vendor. Going that route makes sense from the perspective of how much work you do.

Comment: Thats what I'll try to do. Could the standard shopify sort code work? Or will it require different code?

Comment: I'm pretty new to programming

Comment: TY I found out how to do it by vendor. Pretty simple